# Build string by selecting column in csv

Tags: python, csv

So right now I have a list of timestamp + IDs in a .csv, and I'd like to build a string for each item in the list using parts of the item, for example:

item = 27.02.2015 02:04:00 70002104

I would like to build a string that says "At 27.02.2015 02:04:00 the ID is 70002104"

Right now I'm using the below code, but it gives me the first 19 items in the list for exid followed by the rest of the items for transTime, rather than the first 19 characters of each item in the list as exid and rest as transTime.

```
import time, csv

l = open('InputList.csv')
inputList = csv.reader(l)


for item in inputList:
    exid = item[19:]
    transTime = item[:19]
    print 'At ' + str(transTime) + 'the ID is ' + str(exid)
```

I know this is a clunky way to do this, but I'm new to programming and this is the best I can do.  The way I'd really like to do this is with a .csv that looks like this:

```
Date         Time       exid
--------------------------------
27.02.2015   02:04:00   70002104
27.02.2015   02:54:35   70004630
```

Then for every row in my .csv I'd output my string comprised of a date, time, and exid from each column of that row.

Hopefully that makes sense.  Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings are all in that format, `[date] [time] [id]`, then just [split](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the spaces.

```
with open('InputList.csv') as l:
    inputList = csv.reader(l)
    for item in inputList:
        print('At {} {} the ID is {}'.format(*item.split()))
```

Since your goal is a CSV file, take a look at [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.writer). Note that [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) has support for [writing headers](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader) to a file, but you'll have to write dictionaries:

```
fieldnames = ['Date', 'Time', 'exid']
writer.writerow({fieldnames[i]: e for i, e in enumerate(item.split())})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
t = '27.02.2015 02:04:00 70002104'
timestamp, id = t.rsplit(' ', 1)
print('At %s the Id is %s' % (timestamp, id))
```

or

```
t = '27.02.2015 02:04:00 70002104'
date, time, id = t.split(' ')
print('date =  %s time = %s id = %s' % (date, time, id))
```